# Questions about Qt internationalization

Tags: python, pyqt4, qmake, qtcore, qt-linguist

I am having trouble figuring out how to use Qt to create translation files for a python apllication.

I'm using python 2.7, Qt version 5.9.1 and PyQt4 4.12.1 to create my GUI on OSX 10.11.6.

For now I just wanted to translate a few words on my code.

For what I understand, I have to use QtLinguist to open a .ts file, translate the words and create a .qm file, which will then be used by python.

From [Qt Linguist page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-programmers.html) I get that I need to use a .pro project file, that will be read by `pylupdate4`, etc...

Now, I do I create a .pro file?

I tried running:

```
$ qmake -project myfile.py
$ pylupdate4 myfile.pro -ts file.ts
```

but the resulting .pro file can't be read by `pylupdate4` (`XML error: Parse error at line 1, column 1 [...]`)

From this [Tutorial](https://kuanyui.github.io/2014/09/03/pyqt-i18n/), I tried:

```
$ pylupdate4 myfile.py -ts file.ts
```

Which creates an empty .ts file, that Qt Linguist can't open.

Can someone give my any tip on what might be wrong, the 15 tabs I have open in my browser are not helping.

Here's my python code if you need it:

```
import sys
import os.path as osp
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        # Set MainWindow geometry, use settings of last session. If it's first session,
        # use defaulted settings
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings('Paul',QtCore.QSettings.NativeFormat)
        self.resize(self.settings.value("size", QtCore.QSize(500, 300)).toSize())
        self.move(self.settings.value("pos", QtCore.QPoint(5, 5)).toPoint());

        self.initUI()


    def closeEvent(self, e):
        #Save MainWindow geometry session when closing the window
        self.settings.setValue("size",self.size())
        self.settings.setValue("pos",self.pos())
        e.accept()

    def initUI(self):

        self.hbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self) # Create Vertival box layout to put the buttons
        self.myButtons = QtGui.QPushButton('button',self) #create push button
        self.myButtons.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton { background-color: red; font:bold 20px}""")
        self.myButtons.setToolTip('Push this button')
        self.myButtons.setText(self.tr(QtCore.QString('yes')))
        comboBox=QtGui.QComboBox(self) #create drop down menu
        comboBox.addItem('Portugues')
        comboBox.addItem('English')
        self.hbox.addWidget(comboBox,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignRight) #add drop down menu to box layout
        self.hbox.addStretch(3)      # set separation between buttons
        self.myButtons.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked) # what should the button do
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.myButtons,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignRight) #add button to box layout


        self.setWindowTitle('Test2')


        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):

        msbox= QtGui.QMessageBox()
        choice=msbox.warning(self,'ok',"This button doesn't do anything!!!")


        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.No:
            print('nanan')
        else:
            print('Bye')
            self.settings.setValue("size",self.size());
            self.settings.setValue("pos",self.pos());
            sys.exit()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    translator.load("~/basefiles/translations/qt_pt.qm")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What version of pyqt4 do you have?

Comment: Version 4.12.1, the latest available in Riverbank's download page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use self.tr you must pass the string, not the QString variable, in your case it changes:

```
self.myButtons.setText(self.tr(QtCore.QString('yes')))
```

to

```
self.myButtons.setText(self.tr("yes"))
```

And run everything again.

Comment: Thank you for you help. That would've been a problem later, but it didn't solved my problem now. I still don't know how to create the proper translation files.

Comment: I worked, but let's keep trying, try changing that line to: `self.myButtons.setText(self.tr("yes"))`

Comment: That worked!! Now I can edit the created .ts file with my translations and create the .qm file. I was convinced the problem was when using pylupdate4...

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I hope anyone from search engines like me can get the answer they want.

After giving it a brief try, I found it's very easy to create and update `.ts` file in `PyQt5`.

1. First, you need to create a `.pro` file similar to that in C++ Qt. For example,

```
SOURCES += /path/to/your/python_script \
           /other/python_script

TRANSLATIONS += /path/to/your/translation_file \
                /other/translation_file
```

2. Use command `pylupdate5` to generate `.ts` file

```
pylupdate5 /path/to/your/pro_file
```

If you want to add new translation to `.ts` file (for example, you change your source code), just run this command again. It will update `.ts` file, preserving existing translations.

3. If you want to release a `.ts` file, use command `lrelease-pro-qt5`

```
lrelease-pro-qt5 /path/to/your/pro_file
```